# is_null not working on put method in Laravel

Tags: laravel

**Source code**

```
public function update(Request $request, Department $department, $id)
{
    $department = Department::findOrFail($id);
    if (is_null($department)) {
        return response()->json([
            "data" => [
                "error" => true,
                "message" => "Department not found.",
                "id" => $id
            ]
        ], 404);
    }
    
    $input = $request->all();

    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
    }

    $department->update($request->all());

    return response()->json([
        "data" => [
            "success" => true,
            "message" => "Department update successfully.",
            "data" => $department
        ]
    ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `findOrFail()` will throw an exception if the record is not found, so the check with `is_null()` is unnecessary. Instead of checking for `is_null($department)`, you can handle the exception that `findOrFail()` throws using a try-catch block.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    try {
        $department = Department::findOrFail($id);
        
        $input = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);
        
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
        }

        $department->update($input);
        return response()->json([
            "data" => [
                "success" => true,
                "message" => "Department updated successfully.",
                "data" => $department
            ]
        ], 200);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            "data" => [
                "error" => true,
                "message" => "Department not found.",
                "id" => $id
            ]
        ], 404);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right in this case, but i would propose expand it and to to create an extra method/function to search this id `id` and call/throw exepcion it it at `view, update,delete` calls